# Array of integers with length defined at execution time

Tags: arrays, c, integer, realloc, execution-time

I need to allocate an array of integers within a function and then return it. The problem is that I don't know how much memory I need to allocate: it may be `sizeof(int)*3` as it may be more memory than I got.

Since allocating a big chunk of memory that could be redundant or not enough, is not a nice solution I am going to use `realloc` for the first time.

Now I need to use it in a loop like that

```
for(i = 3; (res[i] = res[i-3] - res[i-2] - res[i-1]) >= 0; i++) {
    
    res = realloc( res, sizeof(long long) * (i+2) );
}
```

Is it allowed to store the address returned from `realloc` in the same pointer given as argument?

And is that a good way to create an array of size defined at execution time?

Comment: The title says "Array of int", but `sizeof(long long)` is used in your code. Which do you actually want to use?

Comment: You are right, I am going to change the title with "integers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the address returned from `realloc` in the same pointer given as argument is allowed, but is not a good way because it will prevent from freeing the allocated memory when `realloc` fails.

It is good to first store the result to another pointer, and assign that to the original variable after checking if the pointer is not `NULL`.

```
for(i = 3; (res[i] = res[i-3] - res[i-2] - res[i-1]) >= 0; i++) {
    
    long long* new_res = realloc( res, sizeof(long long) * (i+2) );
    if (new_res == NULL) {
        /* handle error (print error message, free res, exit program, etc.) */
    } else {
        res = new_res;
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume that the initial allocation is 3. So, the condition in the `for` is assigning a value to `res[i]` _before_ the array is increased. Is this UB?

Comment: Nope the initial allocation is `sizeof(long long) * 4`. Sorry if I didn't post enough context